# Eslint warning due to modules code in source folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lint, create-react-app, react-select

After I import a specific module, in this case, `react-select` from http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/ My react lint prompts me with a ton of lint warning, for example. The code in the module doesn't pass the lint validation. I made a mistake in having modules code in my source file.

```js
Compiled with warnings.

Warning in ./src/~/react-select/lib/index.js

/home/tonyu2/ui/src/node_modules/react-select/lib/index.js
  1:1  warning  'use strict' is unnecessary inside of modules  strict

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)

Warning in ./src/~/react-select/lib/AsyncCreatable.js

/home/tonyu2/ui/src/node_modules/react-select/lib/AsyncCreatable.js
  1:1  warning  'use strict' is unnecessary inside of modules  strict

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)

Warning in ./src/~/react-select/lib/utils/defaultMenuRenderer.js

/home/tonyu2/ui/src/node_modules/react-select/lib/utils/defaultMenuRenderer.js
  1:1  warning  'use strict' is unnecessary inside of modules  strict

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)
You may use special comments to disable some warnings.

Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
```

This is annoying because it affects me from catching the real important error in my code. I am using the create-react-app library so that I don't have to deal with the webpack, bundle, and httpserver.

Comment: Why are you linting the libraries you are using? You typically don't lint libraries with your own lint configuration because it's highly likely they use different settings than you do. Your configuration should only lint the files you created yourself.

Comment: I created the project with create-react-app library. It automatically set up the linting for me. I added the dependency using yarn add react-select. Did I do something wrong when I add the dependency that cause the linting problem?

Comment: The path to the library, `./src/~/react-select/lib/index.js`, is strange. What command did you run to start your app? What command did you run to add 'react-select'?

Comment: Does `/home/tonyu2/ui/src/` have its own 'package.json' file?

Comment: Correct! I accidentally run npm install on src/ file. I deleted the package.json file but forgot to delete the modules folder.

Comment: Shall I keep this post for other's reference? @RossAllen if you like you can post a solution under this post.

Comment: Great! Yup, let's leave it open and I will vote to close it as a one-time error. It will still be here but let future visitors know it was a transient error.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried running npm install first and checked your package.json file? That is usually my problem.

Comment: I install by yarn add react-select. They are installed on the right dev environment, if that's what you worry about.